# Making HDD to spindown when not mounted but to keep it spinning while mounted

Tags: linux, hard-drive, ssd, power-consumption, hdparm

Is it possible to make harddisk spin when it's mounted and to stop spinning when I unmount it?

I was finding answers on the internet, but there is not any precise answer for such a question. There is always said to put timeout on harddisk or to use

```
hdparm -Y /dev/sdX
```

but I mean, they just partially solve my answer. Okey, I can do such thing that when I acces HDD (my primary disk is SSD) it starts spinning and after I quit working with it, I'll unmount it and simply run that command... but it's irritating. I mean it's computer so there must be any way to automatize such thing, code some script or whatever. I also use TLP, but TLP makes HDD only to timeout, so it doesn't solve my problem.

There can be question why I would need that, why it's not enough just to set timeout. There are 2 answers for it:

1. When Im using HDD, I primarily watch movies or listen to music (which are on it), and if there would be timeout on HDD it would be stopping and starting again and again and again, because OS will be always reading from it and that approach will be tearing HDD because of starting->stopping->starting cycle.
2. As I have laptop, not desktop, I'd like to preserve battery whenever it's possible. When the HDD is not mounted, I know that I'm not working with it and so then there is no reason for harddisk to be spinning.

Timeout is good, but because of the 1st reason, it's not (best) solution for me.
If someone knows how to help, feel free to write, I'd appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: There are more people that think that a harddisk's lifetime can be extended by not making it spin... I can tell you, a harddisk will get bad sectors far sooner than it will be worn due to the spinning. IMHO this is a waste of effort. I can understand the power consumption part, but not the wear on the motor...

Comment: There is nothing to argue about your post as I want just the same. When I have mounted HDD I know I'm about to use it, so there is no reason to stop spinning HDD (1 in my question). But when I unmount HDD I'm pretty sure I will not be using it until I mount it again so there is no reason for it to be spinning and so laptop can preserve more battery.

Comment: If you want to really save power replace the HDD with an SSD and then you don't have to waste power on motors at all.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the drive the timeouts can be quite long. Usually far longer than it takes to play a music track.  `hdparm` can show you the available timeouts for the drive and should show the cureent and recommended values for your drive.

Other than old server drives, the recommendations I have seen are to spin drives down if they have been idle for several minutes.  All the drives I have checked in the last few years are pre-configured to spin down when inactive.

You may want to check wether the O/S has spun down the drive when you dismounted it.  I believe you can query this with `hdparm`.   If it isn't spinning down the drive, write a short script to dismount and spin down the drive when you want to stop using it.

Comment: Well that actually is what I want. Some script which will make my HDD to be always spinning while it is mounted and to spin it down when I dismount my HDD, but I don't know where to write such script, that is the issue.

Comment: As you are likely the only one using the script, I would put it in `/usr/local/bin`.  The unmount script needs to do the `unmount` and `hdparm` commands.

Comment: But if it will be in '/usr/local/bin' wouldn't I need to run it always manually?

Comment: Yes, but it would replace the current commands you are using to mount and unmount the drive.

Comment: can you help with making a script? I'm just a starting guy with Linux and in that folder, there are couple of programs and I just don't know if to rewrite some or just to add or what... I would be grateful if you could help me out with this.